# Multiple rows to multiple columns for co-applicant name and address for a unique ID

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

This is the query

```
SELECT b.ID, e.customername AS "Applicant name",
       f.address AS "Applicant address",
       x.customername AS "Co-Applicant name",
       x.address AS "Co-Applicant address"
  FROM table_1 b,
       table_2 e,
       table_3 f,
       (SELECT b.customername, g.agreementid, a.address
          FROM table_2 g, table_4 x, table_2 b, table_3 a
         WHERE g.ID = x.ID
           AND b.customerid = x.custid
           AND b.customerid = a.custid
           AND x.flag <> 'G') x
 WHERE b.custid = e.customerid
   AND f.custid = b.lesseeid
   AND f.bptype = 'LS'
   AND f.mailingaddress = 'Y'
   AND b.ID = x.ID
   AND b.ID='101'
```

The data is coming in below format.

```
+-----+-------+----------+--------------+----------+
| ID  | name  | address  | co-applicant | address  |
+-----+-------+----------+--------------+----------+
| 101 | aamir | address1 | rahul        | London   |
| 101 | aamir | address1 | vijay        | Paris    |
| 101 | aamir | address1 | sanjay       | New York |
+-----+-------+----------+--------------+----------+
```

I need the data in below format

[![ID   name     address     name_1      address     name_2      address
101  aamir  address1     rahul       London      vijay       Paris

102 Anil    address2    Suyash  Mumbai  Rajesh  Delhi   Prakash Kolkata][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDqlm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDqlm.png)

Comment: Please provide input value,expected output on site, not as image so that while helping they can use the inserts and updates. Also, post what you have tried to get the desire output.

Comment: Aamir Khan, Are no of co-applicant fixed or they are variabe?

Comment: number of applicant can be maximum of 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` as following:

```
SQL> WITH DATAA AS
  2  (
  3  SELECT 101 ID, 'aamir' name, 'address1' address, 'rahul' co_applicant, 'london' co_address FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 101, 'aamir', 'address1', 'vijay', 'Paris' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 101, 'aamir', 'address1', 'sanjay', 'New York' FROM DUAL
  6  )
  7  -- YOUR QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
  8  SELECT * FROM
  9      (
 10          SELECT
 11              T.*,
 12              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) AS RN
 13          FROM DATAA T
 14      ) PIVOT (
 15          MAX ( CO_APPLICANT ) AS NAME, MAX ( CO_ADDRESS ) AS ADDRESS
 16          FOR RN IN ( 1, 2,3 )
 17      );

        ID NAME  ADDRESS  1_NAME 1_ADDRES 2_NAME 2_ADDRES 3_NAME 3_ADDRES
---------- ----- -------- ------ -------- ------ -------- ------ --------
       101 aamir address1 rahul  london   vijay  Paris    sanjay New York

SQL>
```

**Note:** It will generate only 3 combinations of name and address as oracle do not allow dynamic columns in the query. If there is more than 3 co-applicant exist then it will take only data of 3 co-applicants.

**-- UPDATE --**

Use `PARTITION BY` clause in `ROW_NUMBER` if you multiple IDs as following:

> ```
> SQL> WITH DATAA AS
>   2      (
>   3      SELECT 101 ID, 'aamir' name, 'address1' address, 'rahul' co_applicant, 'london' co_address FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   4      SELECT 101, 'aamir', 'address1', 'vijay', 'Paris' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   5      SELECT 101, 'aamir', 'address1', 'sanjay', 'New York' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   6      SELECT 102 ID, 'Tejash' name, 'address2' address, 'chetan' co_applicant, 'london' co_address FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   7      SELECT 102, 'Tejash', 'address2', 'nirav', 'Paris' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   8      SELECT 102, 'Tejash', 'address2', 'pulkit', 'New York' FROM DUAL
>   9      )
>  10      -- YOUR QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
>  11      SELECT * FROM
>  12          (
>  13             SELECT
>  14                 T.*,
>  15                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY NULL) AS RN
>  16             FROM DATAA T
>  17         ) PIVOT (
>  18             MAX ( CO_APPLICANT ) AS NAME, MAX ( CO_ADDRESS ) AS ADDRESS
>  19             FOR RN IN ( 1, 2,3 )
>  20         );
>
>         ID NAME   ADDRESS  1_NAME 1_ADDRES 2_NAME 2_ADDRES 3_NAME 3_ADDRES
> ---------- ------ -------- ------ -------- ------ -------- ------ --------
>        101 aamir  address1 rahul  london   vijay  Paris    sanjay New York
>        102 Tejash address2 chetan london   nirav  Paris    pulkit New York
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: It is working for one ID, but my records have multiple IDs and multiple column related to unique IDs.

Comment: Ok, You can use PARTITION BY clause in row_number as mentioned in the UPDATE section

Comment: Great @tejash it works. One more help, how to alter the position of the columns that are coming through PIVOT?

Comment: Either change the order in the `FOR RN IN ( 1, 2,3 )` or to change more specific order use outer select.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can first do the conditional aggregation and then can join back with table -

```
WITH DATAA AS (SELECT 101 ID, 'aamir' name, 'address1' address, 'rahul' co_applicant, 'london' co_address FROM DUAL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 101, 'aamir', 'address1', 'vijay', 'Paris' FROM DUAL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 101, 'aamir', 'address1', 'sanjay', 'New York' FROM DUAL
               ),
     TEMP AS (select D.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY co_applicant) RN from DATAA D)
SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN CO_APPLICANT ELSE NULL END) AS name_1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN CO_ADDRESS   ELSE NULL END) AS ADDRESS_1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN CO_APPLICANT ELSE NULL END) AS name_2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN CO_ADDRESS   ELSE NULL END) AS ADDRESS_2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN CO_APPLICANT ELSE NULL END) AS name_3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN CO_ADDRESS   ELSE NULL END) AS ADDRESS_3
FROM TEMP
GROUP BY ID, NAME, ADDRESS;
```

With the clarification as SQL tables represent unordered sets until you specify a deterministic order clause. So I use an order by clause as co_applicant name. Thus from your sample data Sanjay is coming on 2nd col and Vihjay is coming in 3rd col.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eeda9eefefe8bf07ac56cd07d193cff6) is the fiddle.